# How to Unclick a Table Cell in React

Tags: css, reactjs, html-table, onclick

I have a table I've built in React. I want to be able to color a cell if I click on it, and uncolor it if I click on a different cell (the new cell would get colored instead).

I can successfully color cells when I click on them, but I'm not sure how to uncolor them, since the cell object doesn't know when a different cell has been clicked on. (I can't think of anything in the row/table object that would know either, though.) As a result, I end up with a bunch of colored cells if I click multiple times, instead of just one.

Here is my cell code:

```
class Cell extends React.Component {

    state = {
        bgColor: 'inherit'
      }

    handleClick = (columnId) => {
        this.setState({
            bgColor: "blue"
        })
    }

    render() {

        const content = this.props.content;

        return (
            <td
                onClick={()=> this.handleClick()}
                style={{backgroundColor: this.state.bgColor}}
            >
                {content}
            </td>
        )
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can successfully color cells when I click on them, but I'm not sure
> how to uncolor them, since the cell object doesn't know when a
> different cell has been clicked on

You need a single source of truth so that your components know who is active. In the example below, I put the `activeCell` state on a parent component `App` so that this will hold the true value of who is active. Pass the props down the to `Cell` as needed for the updating of  the new `activeCell` on-click

```js
class Cell extends React.Component {
  render() {

    const content = this.props.content;

    return (
      <td
          onClick={()=>{this.props.handleChangeActiveCell(this.props.identifier)}}
          style={{backgroundColor: this.props.activeCell === true ? this.props.bgColor : 'inherit'}}
      >
          {content}
      </td>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    bgColor: "blue",
    activeCell: -1
  }
  
  handleChangeActiveCell = (key) => {
    this.setState({
      activeCell: key
    });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <React.Fragment>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <Cell 
              identifier={0} 
              handleChangeActiveCell={this.handleChangeActiveCell} 
              activeCell={this.state.activeCell === 0 ? true : false} 
              bgColor={this.state.bgColor} 
              content={`sample_content`}
            />
            
            <Cell 
              identifier={1} 
              handleChangeActiveCell={this.handleChangeActiveCell} 
              activeCell={this.state.activeCell === 1 ? true : false} 
              bgColor={this.state.bgColor} 
              content={`sample_content`}
            />
          </tr>
        </table>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
td {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense!

Comment: You are welcome. This will be a common practice in your applications moving forward. Remember that if component A & component B needs to know each others state, you can let **their parent** keep that state and pass the state down as props to both components then perform some logic. If that "state" needs to persist all throughout the app, you can consider using React Context.

Comment: Yes, your answer clarified that practice for me a lot. :)